# How to use \newlinechar and \endlinechar primitives to output position information at the beginning and end of each line of text?

Tags: positioning, paragraphs, line, primitives

If I want to use the \newlinechar and \endlinechar primitives to output the position information at the beginning and end of each line of text, what should I do?

Comment: `\newlinechar` and `\endlinechar` are internal registers, they have no role whatsoever when typesetting, other than making TeX aware of the integer stored in them (and `\newlinechar` is only relevant with `\write`).

Comment: I think you need to be clearer what your intended output is. You seem to be asking about lines in the typeset _output_ but neither of those primitives is related to that. `\newlinechar` makes newlines in `\write` and `\typeout` etc. `\endlinechar` is the character added to each line of the _source_

Comment: I want to know the start and end coordinates of each line in the pdf generated by latex rendering. I hope to automatically generate line coordinate information for all text lines in the entire pdf by redefining some related primitives.

Comment: you can not really get that information from classical tex commands

Comment: Because I have learned that by redefining \everypar, I can output some content at the beginning of each paragraph, so I am exploring whether there are corresponding primitives that can help me get position information at the beginning and end of each line.

Comment: No, they can't give you line information, unless you make some assumptions. You can use the latex paragraph hooks (better than using everypar directly) to get thestart and end of the paragraph so if you assume normal text and even line sacing you can guess the line positions but if any line is over-large and line spacing is disturbed you can not access the line positions from TeX.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about lines in the typeset output but neither of those primitives is related to that. `\newlinechar` makes newlines in `\write` and `\typeout` etc. `\endlinechar` is the character added to each line of the source.

You can use the latex paragraph hooks (better than using everypar directly) to get the start and end of the paragraph so if you assume normal text and even line spacing you can guess the line positions but if any line is over-large and line spacing is disturbed you can not access the line positions from TeX.

Comment: You might add that "breaking paragraphs into lines" is rather dynamic, and a very small change in a paragraph can change where lines start and end, except at the beginning and end of the paragraph itself.